# Make 2 digit number to a 3 digit number and reverse it

Tags: java, reverse

`99` to `099` and reverse it = `990`

This is my code but it's not changing the `number`. Why?

```
int number = 99;
String strI = String.format("%03d", number);
new StringBuilder(strI).reverse().toString();
number = Integer.parseInt(strI);
return number;
```

Answer (score 6):

You aren't assigning the result of `toString` back to `strI`.

I think you wanted

```
strI = new StringBuilder(strI).reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String strI = String.format("%03d", number);
strI = new StringBuilder(strI).reverse().toString(); //Capture the result into strI
number = Integer.parseInt(strI);
return number;
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternate non-string version (faster):

```
int number = 99, result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++, number /= 10)
    result = result * 10 + number % 10;
return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the output of `StringBuilder` to a variable and use that variable for Integer parsing.

**Example**

```
public class Reverse {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = String.format("%03d", 99);
        String o = new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();
        int number = Integer.parseInt(o);
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```